# Representation of a Function on Natural Numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Could you help me with an example and explanation on what actually would be a function on $\mathbb{N}$?

I am told that it can be identified as a sequence $(f_i)$ and it can be written as

$$f(k)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{\{i\}}(k)$$

where $\mathbb{1}_i(k)$ is the charachteristic function.

but this seems too abstract and I cannot grasp it. Maybe a simple example will help

Comment: I'm not sure whether I've understood your question. $$f(x) = x \text{ where } x\in\mathbb{N}$$ is an example of a function on natural numbers

Comment: Ok, so then a function on $\mathbb{N}$ is one that takes a natural number and maps it into a natural number? I guess, I can see it then. The representation for example for $f(k)=k$ will just have $f_i = 0,1,2,3....$ and the summation above will produce the same as $f(k)=k$. Probably this is not a unique representation though, right?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is at all. Can you rephrase it in a single sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think looking at the example of a finite set might help. Let's say we have a function on the set $\{0,1,2\}$ so that $f(0)=6$, $f(1)=\pi$, and $f(2)=\sqrt{2}$ (these numbers don't actually matter much). We can write $f$ as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}6&\mathrm{if}\ x=0\\\pi&\mathrm{if}\ x=1\\\sqrt{2}&\mathrm{if}\ x=2.\end{cases}$$

The magic happens because we can write these cases as

\begin{multline*}
f(x)=6\cdot\left[1\mathrm{\ if\ }x=0\mathrm{\ and\ }0\mathrm{\ otherwise}\right]\\
+\pi\cdot\left[1\mathrm{\ if\ }x=1\mathrm{\ and\ }0\mathrm{\ otherwise}\right]\\
+\sqrt{2}\cdot\left[1\mathrm{\ if\ }x=2\mathrm{\ and\ }0\mathrm{\ otherwise}\right],
\end{multline*}

which can be written very concisely as

$$f(x)=6\cdot \textbf{1}_0(x)+\pi\cdot \textbf{1}_1(x)+\sqrt{2}\cdot \textbf{1}_2(x)$$

with indicator functions. What you've written here is no different from this, except that $\mathbb{N}$ is an infinite set instead of a finite set. In general, we can write any function $f:S\to T$ as

$$f(x)=\sum_{i\in S} f(i)\textbf{1}_i(x),$$

as the only nonzero term inside the summation is the one where $x=i$.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.